Curved beam on tikz
I am trying to reproduce the image below :

I am not sure how to implement the « curvature » of the beam and adding the axis as a consequence of that is difficult.
Can you help me?
Thank you

\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  %% defining the corners of the grill
  \coordinate (grill/sw) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (grill/ne) at ($(grill/sw)+(5in,1cm)$);
  \coordinate (grill/nw) at (grill/sw|-grill/ne);
  \coordinate (grill/se) at (grill/sw-|grill/ne);

  %% filling the grill
  \draw[fill=gray!20] (grill/sw) rectangle (grill/ne);
 \draw[red, thick, Stealth-Stealth] (0.6,0) -- (0.6,1) node[pos = 0.5, right]{$h$};
  \draw[black, thick, -Stealth] (0,-0.6) -- (0,0) node[scale = 0.6,pos = 0.5, left]{$\frac{V_{a}}{2}$};
    \draw[black, thick, -Stealth] (12.7,-0.6) -- (12.7,0) node[scale = 0.6,pos = 0.5, right]{$\frac{V_{a}}{2}$};
  %% downward arrows 
  \def\myarrowheight{1cm}
  \def\myarrowcount{12}
  \foreach \myn in {0,1,...,\myarrowcount}
  {
    \draw[arrows=Stealth-] ($(grill/nw)!\myn/\myarrowcount!(grill/ne)$) -- ++ (0,\myarrowheight);
  }
  %% label above downward arrows
  \path ([yshift=\myarrowheight+2ex]grill/nw) --
        ([yshift=\myarrowheight+2ex]grill/ne)
        node[midway] {$V_a$};

  \def\myr{1.5ex}
% Length label
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myyshift{5ex+2*\myr}
  \begin{scope}[myshift/.style={yshift={-\myyshift}}]

     \path
           ([myshift]grill/sw)
           --
           ([myshift]grill/se)
           node [midway] {L}
           edge[arrows=-Stealth] ([myshift]grill/se)
           edge[arrows=-Stealth] ([myshift]grill/sw);
     \foreach \myn in {se,sw}
     {
       \draw ([myshift]grill/\myn)
             edge ++(up:3ex)
             edge ++(down:3ex);       
     }  

  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}


Purely for comparison, here is a Metapost alternative.

\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

  numeric wd; wd = 300;

  path xx, yy;
  xx = origin -- (1.2wd, 0);
  yy = origin -- (0, -1/5 wd);

  path c; c = origin .. (1/2 wd, -1/16 wd) {right} .. (wd, 0);
  path beam; beam = 
         10 down rotated angle direction 0 of c shifted point 0 of c {direction 0 of c}
      .. 10 down rotated angle direction 1 of c shifted point 1 of c {direction 1 of c}
      .. 10 down rotated angle direction 2 of c shifted point 2 of c {direction 2 of c}
      -- 10 up rotated angle direction 2 of c shifted point 2 of c {-direction 2 of c}
      .. 10 up rotated angle direction 1 of c shifted point 1 of c {-direction 1 of c}
      .. 10 up rotated angle direction 0 of c shifted point 0 of c {-direction 0 of c}
      -- cycle;

  % nice arrows
  ahangle := 30;
  ahlength := 5;

  % axes
  drawarrow xx withcolor 1/2; label.rt("$x$", point 1 of xx);
  drawarrow yy withcolor 1/2; label.bot("$y$", point 1 of yy);

  % label L
  drawoptions(withcolor 1/2 blue);
  path a; a = (point -1/2 of beam -- point 5/2 of beam) shifted 45 up;
  draw (30 down -- 15 up) shifted point 0 of a;
  draw (30 down -- 15 up) shifted point 1 of a;
  drawdblarrow a;  
  picture t; t = thelabel("$L$", point 1/2 of a);
  unfill bbox t; draw t;
  drawoptions();

  % the beam
  draw beam;
  draw c dashed evenly;
  for t=0, 2: draw point t of c withpen pencircle scaled 3; endfor

  % vectors
  drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1 withcolor 2/3 red);
  path a; a = (30 up -- origin) shifted point 4 of beam;
  drawarrow a; label.rt("$V_a$", point 1/4 of a);
  
  numeric t;
  (t, whatever) = beam intersectiontimes yy;
  path a; a = (30 down -- origin) shifted point t of beam;
  drawarrow a; label.lft("$\frac12 V_a$", point 1/2 of a);
  path a; a = (30 down -- origin) shifted point 2-t of beam;
  drawarrow a; label.rt("$\frac12 V_a$", point 1/2 of a);
  drawoptions();

  % other labels
  drawoptions(withcolor 1/4 green);
  path w; w = (xpart point 1/2 of c, 0) -- point 1/2 of c;
  drawarrow w; label.top("$w$", point 0 of w);

  path h; h = (down -- up) scaled 30 shifted point 4/3 of c;
  drawarrow h cutafter beam; label.urt("$h$", point 0 of h);
  drawarrow reverse h cutafter subpath (3,4) of beam;
drawoptions();

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

You need to compile this with lualatex.  Follow the link at the top for introductions and manuals for Metapost.

You can use some non-linear transformations. I will show an example here (it's not a direct answer to your question, but I think you can adapt it quite easily --- I have no time now, sorry). You probably should do a bit more gimmick to have the vertical parts slanted, but this could be a start.
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,patterns}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\makeatletter
% transform the space so that it is sloping down in a y^3 way
% thanks to @marmot!
\def\thirdpowertransformation{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myX}{\pgf@x}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myY}{-0.01*\pgf@x*0.01*\pgf@x*0.1*\pgf@x+\pgf@y}
    \setlength{\pgf@x}{\myX pt}
    \setlength{\pgf@y}{\myY pt}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ]
    \path[use as bounding box] (-0.2,-3.5) rectangle (4.7,1.5);
    % lateral view
    % not flexed bar
    \fill [pattern=north west lines] (-0.2, -0.5) rectangle ++(0.4,1.4);
    \draw [fill=white] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.4);
    \draw [dashed] (0,0.2) -- (4,0.2);
    \fill (2,0.4) rectangle ++(0.7,0.1);
    \fill (3.2,0.4) rectangle ++(0.2,0.1);
    % flexed bar (use coordinate transformation!)
    \begin{scope}[color=red]
        \pgftransformnonlinear{\thirdpowertransformation}
        \draw  (0,0) rectangle (4,0.4);
        \draw [dashed] (0,0.2) -- (4,0.2);
        \fill (2,0.4) rectangle ++(0.7,0.1);
        \fill (3.2,0.4) rectangle ++(0.2,0.1);
        \coordinate (a) at (2.25,0.5);
        \coordinate (b) at (3.3,0.5);
        \draw [thick,red,->] (4,0.2) -- ++(0,-1) node[right]{$P$};
    \end{scope}
    \draw [thick, blue, <-] (a) -- ++(.5,.5) node[above right]{$+\varepsilon$};
    \draw [thick, blue, <-] (b) -- ++(-.5,-.5) node[below left]{$\varepsilon=0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

In the scope environment, I redraw the beam with a non-linear transformation that adds to the y coordinate a polynomial function of the current x; the result is:

